# Passing custom variable to form validation

Tags: symfony

I try to pass my variable to constraint in form validator, but can't.
i'm doing that:

```
$payForm = $this->createForm(new CableTVPayType(), null, array('balance' => $balance));
```

And in CableTVPayType:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    $maxSumm = $options['balance'] - 100;
    [...]
```

It works fine, my maxSumm is what i want, but Symfiony checks $options array. 'balance' isn't a default option, and complain about this:

```
The option "balance" does not exist
```

Is there another, more right way to pass custom variable to validation?

Comment: BTW, your question is misleading. You're asking about validation, while the code examples are about passing custom options to a form type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with this!

Crate variable for a class, and passing value to it through construct method

```
class CableTVPayType extends AbstractType {

    private $maxSumm;

    public function __construct($maxSumm) {
        $this->maxSumm = $maxSumm;
    }
```

Create form with argument

```
$payForm = $this->createForm(new CableTVPayType($someValue));
```

Now i can use this variable as i want in my form.

Comment: Don't use the constructor for instance specific stuff. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

Use the constructor for stuff to be used by **all** instances of a type. For example, your type might need an entity manager for it to work. It will be reused across all the form instances.

For instance specific stuff use options. If you use the constructor for instance specific stuff, all the instances will get the value you pass to the constructor of the first instance.

```php
/**
 * @FormType
 */
class PayType extends AbstractType {

    private $someService;

    /**
     * @InjectParams
     */
    public function __construct(SomeService $someService)
    {
        $this->someService = $someService;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'balance' => 0
        );
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'pay';
    }
}
```

```php
$form = $this->createForm('pay', null, array('balance' => $balance));
```

Note that the `@FormType` annotation registers the type as a service. It allows you to use the type's name instead of creating an instance manually. It gets even more convenient when a type needs a service to be injected into it. You use just the name — `pay` in this case — instead of something like this:

```php
$form = $this->createForm(new PayType($this->get('some_service')), null, array(
    'balance' => $balance
));
```

Comment: Apparently it's not with `getDefaultOptions()` anymore, but with `setDefaultOptions()`.

Otherwise it says 

> The option "no_animal_type" does not exist. Known options are:  "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", ...